# Unable to export/validate archive in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm trying to export my IOS app with Xcode 7 for testing, since this is the first time I'm trying this, I ran into some problems along the way. Now one issue I can't seem to fix is that after I've archived the app, I can't validate and/or export it. These 2 buttons are greyed out. Frustrating part is that I managed it to do it but I've selected the wrong option, when I actually wanted the 'ad hoc' version of it. So I've tried it again and now it won't work. 
Any ideas what I have missed or what settings I should make sure to be set right?

[greyed out buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRIVu.png)

Comment: Check development and distribution certificates in your mac keychain and also you need to logout one time from Xcode preference and add it again. Hope this process may solve your issue.

Comment: @iOS_Binod Thank you for your reply! I saw that I only have a develop certificate. Do I need a distribution one for only making it possible to test the app? Because i'm also logged in with my Apple ID. As you can see in the picture i've uploaded, the only option i have is to click the link to the enrollment.

Comment: Yes, your system must have distribution certificate as well as app distribution provisioning profile to generate IPA file from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Preferences->Accounts` and check that you're logged in

Answer (score 0):

Check your network connection after it go to `Xcode > Preferences > Accounts` check if you are login or not, if not login with `Developer Account` and do your steps again.